# jquery click not latching onto bootstrap col-md div

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, wow.js

I have a div that's simply defined as:

```
<div class="col-md-4 single-signup wow fadeIn animated" data-wow-offset="10" data-wow-duration="1.5s">
```

In it is some content, such as the following:

```
<p><a id="clickme" href="#">Please do!</a> click click click.</p>
```

The problem is, my event handler isn't working at all for this. The event looks like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#clickme').click(function(){
    alert("test");
  });
});
```

Now, what's odd is that when I remove all the bootstrap/wow animations out of the div class, and just have a raw `<div></div>`, the handler works as expected.

What could possibly be causing the issue here?

Comment: Well - which is it? Removing Bootstrap? Or removing wow?  (That will tell you more about where the problem comes in.  I strongly suspect it's the wow).

Comment: Is your javascript running before the DOM is loaded? Wrap your click handler in `$(function() { ...your code... });`

Comment: I should have specified that, it's already wrapped in `$(document).ready(), I'll edit to reflect

Comment: This *should* work so I'm guessing it's an error elsewhere. Maybe a simple syntax error. Post your actual code?

Comment: No way to answer this without knowing what `wow` is used for or what scripts do to it. Sounds like the inner html is being modified and replaced as html which would remove existing event listeners

Comment: I think charlietfl nailed it, can you try `$(document).on('click', '#clickme', function(){
    alert("test");
  });` ?

Comment: @charlietfl I'm guessing that's what's happening also. I figured using some kind of `live` event binder might resolve that. but alas not. I'll just have to repost with more code.

Answer (score 1):

If the inner html is being modified then replaced by another plugin then that replacement can remove existing event listeners.

You can use event delegation assuming that your `id="clickme"` still exists after modification

```
$(document).on('click', '#clickme', function(){
   alert("test");
});
```